# I can't get https://sendsonar.com working but sendsonar.com and https://www.sendsonar.com work just fine

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, https, godaddy, heroku

I'm trying to get our domain - https://sendsonar.com - to go to https://www.sendsonar.com but for some reason this is failing. Here's the curl output:

```
yo@ubuntu-i386:~/Sonar$ curl -kvI https://sendsonar.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://sendsonar.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 50.63.202.28...
* Connected to sendsonar.com (50.63.202.28) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sendsonar.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sendsonar.com:443
```

Here's the curl output if I go to https:/www.sendsonar.com

```
yo@ubuntu-i386:~/Sonar$ curl -kvI https://www.sendsonar.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.sendsonar.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 50.19.125.31...
* Connected to www.sendsonar.com (50.19.125.31) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
...and so on
```

Our domain and ssl certificate were purchased from Godaddy and the server is on Heroku.

I'm not sure whether it's a setting in Godaddy, or Heroku and have dug around all I can with my limited knowledge.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, kudos for using the correct hostnames, it makes it **much** easier to help you! Second - the curl output shows that the two hosts live on separate IP addresses. It would help greatly if you would include the configuration information for both servers/apache instances/virtualhosts, whichever is applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're using GoDaddy to redirect https://sendsonar.com/ to the Heroku-hosted `www` subdomain. GoDaddy's DNS manager's redirects don't support HTTPS (as GoDaddy's redirect services servers don't have your SSL certificate installed).

Comment: We fixed the issue by removing the www redirect, signing up for dnsimple.com, and then setting up the appropriate CNAMEs in dnsimple. That fixed the issue for us.

Comment: @VishalPatel Looks like you got ALIAS records set up nicely (different from a standard CNAME in a few important ways). They're one of a few providers with that handy feature.